# Which sources can I use to study botany and horticulture?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, literature

I refer with this question to those among you who have a strong background and work in fields like: botanics, horticulture, dendrology, etc.

I would like to start building a solid preparation, both practical and theoretical, in horticulture, with a strong scientific background.

I am a physicist at the moment, but I am trying to lay the basis for a career switch. In September I will attend the RHS courses, but in the meanwhile I would like to start studying something on my own.

Is there any introductory, basic, read that you would suggest? Also, if any of you have in mind a sort of "curriculum" (in terms of subjects, books, etc.) or would like to play with it, this would be of great help! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I had an earlier version of Raven's [*Biology of Plants*](http://www.amazon.com/Raven-Biology-Plants-Loose-Leaf-Evert/dp/1464117802) for botany/plant physiology classes and liked it, and the current version should be a very good start. [Here is a review](http://aob.oxfordjournals.org/content/113/7/vii.1.full) of the current version of *Biology of Plants* from Annals of Botany.

Comment: I like 'Plant Physiological Ecology". Thijs Pons is one of the authors.

Answer (score 4):

This book could be a good start: [Botany by Mauseth](http://books.google.com.co/books/about/Botany.html?id=0BGEs95p5EsC&redir_esc=y). However if you don't have any knowledge about biology I suggest you to get starting with the basics of cellular biology. A good book could be "The cell" by Cooper, you can find it in electronic version.  There are many books about cellular biology but I recommended this because it is complete and detailed without being too long compared with others.